# Code: ErrorItemNotFound\r\nMessage: The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties

Tags: c#, .net, console-application, azure-ad-graph-api

we are implementing a console application which will read shared mail(Shared@***.com) box messages.
we are getting Token by providing Service account(ServiceAccount@***.com) username and password.
we have all required delegate permission like **Mail.ReadWrite.Shared,Mail.ReadWrite,User.ReadWrite.All.**

we are able fetch token.but while trying access Shared mail box mail folders, it was throwing an error as:

**Code: ErrorItemNotFound\r\nMessage: The specified object was not found in the store., The process failed to get the correct properties.**

but we are able to access Service account mail box, not able to access Shared mail box mail folder.

the code which I have used is:

```
await graphServiceClient.Users["devpdidata@deloitte.com"].MailFolders.Inbox.Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

and i have tried with:

```
await graphServiceClient.Users["devpdidata@deloitte.com"].Messages.Request().GetAsync();
```

but still I'm getting the same issue.
How can I resolve this issue please?

Comment: have you shared the `Shared@.com`'s mail box with ServiceAccount@.com?

Comment: If the answer is helpful, please accept it as answer( click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in). Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `ServiceAccount@.com` to your shared mailbox(`devpdidata@deloitte.com`).

Just go to Microsoft 365 admin center, select your shared mailbox and add `ServiceAccount@.com`

[image]

**Note: It might take up to 60 minutes for the change to be effective in Outlook and OWA.**

Then you will be able to access the Shared mail box mail folder.

[image]